# Is it posible to write greasemonkey script or add-on for firefox to automaticly add security exception?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Is it posible to write greasemonkey script or add-on for firefox to automaticly add security exception ?

I have plenty of dumb users and I really need to automate this for two of my intranet pages which have wrong certificates.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I need thus tool also, I use gappporxy, and wanna batchly add "1.docs.google.com", "2.docs.google.com", "3.docs.googl.com" ... into ssl security exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope not as that would be a *huge* security hole ! You should create correct certificates for your sites instead. Create a CA and install the public CA certificate on your user's browser so the site certificates will be valid. There are plenty of articles and howtos found via Google that explain how to roll your own CA and create certificates for your sites.

Comment: I know this and I agree, but IT says that at least for now we'll keep this certificates.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not possible in Greasemonkey.  It is *probably* possible with a Firefox extension -- but then what about users on other browsers?

First, is the problem caused by "www.yourserver.com" versus "yourserver.com" (or some other subdomain issue)?
If so, set redirects so that "www.yourserver.com" always maps to "yourserver.com", and/or switch from a subdomain to a subfolder structure ("somesite.yourserver.com" becomes "yourserver.com/somesite/" instead).

If that's not it, then as Darkdust said, either (1) Get your boss to help you pressure the IT department or (2) Go around the IT department.

You [can get valid certificates](http://www.namecheap.com/learn/other-services/ssl-certificates.asp) for as little as $10.  Sometimes it takes a little tweaking on an intranet, but it's doable.